# What do the different plans of NSolid SaaS include?

Tags: node.js, performance, nsolid

I'm interested on testing NSolid for my Node.js app, and saw there is a new SaaS version.

In your [pricing webpage](https://www.nodesource.com/products/pricing) you show different plans. What are the main differences among them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main differences are the number of process you are allowed to monitor and the number of users you can invite to use that subscription, you choose one in relation with the size of your organization and the amount of processes you currently have. In case your numbers are higher than any of the offerings, you can contact Sales for a custom quote for a custom SaaS plan that fits your needs.